# How to combine QueryBuilder in TypeORM?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

for example:

```
    const tempResult = await this.userRepository
    .createQueryBuilder('user')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('user.products', 'product')
    .where('product.id = :productId', { productId: option.productId })
    .getManyAndCount();
```

when the option.productId's value is `''`,I want query all.

now my code is like this:

```
    let tempResult = null;
    if (option.productId) {
      tempResult = await this.userRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('user')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('user.products', 'product')
        .where('product.id = :productId', { productId: option.productId })
        .getManyAndCount();
    } else {
      tempResult = await this.userRepository.createQueryBuilder('user').getManyAndCount();
    }
```

But when where query is too much，the code is so bad like:

```
    let tempResult = null;
    if (option.productId && option.organizationId) {
      tempResult = await this.userRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('user')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('user.products', 'product')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('user.organization', 'organization')
        .where('product.id = :productId', { productId: option.productId })
        .where('organization.id = :organizationId', { organizationId: option.organizationId })
        .getManyAndCount();
    } else if (option.productId) {
      tempResult = await this.userRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('user')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('user.products', 'product')
        .where('product.id = :productId', { productId: option.productId })
        .getManyAndCount();
    } else if (option.organizationId) {
      tempResult = await this.userRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('user')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('user.organization', 'organization')
        .where('organization.id = :organizationId', { organizationId: option.organizationId })
        .getManyAndCount();
    } else {
      tempResult = await this.userRepository.createQueryBuilder('user').getManyAndCount();
    }
```

Is there a better way to combine QueryBuilder in TypeORM?

Comment: What do you mean by “but when where query too much?”

Comment: @AWebb hello,I have edited new demo code.

Comment: Regardless what you do with TypeORM you're just going to refact what you already have. Personally, I would create different queries for each scenario and then call them conditionally from the client. That way you aren't running conditionals every time this query is being called. Instead the client conditionals request for each specific scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make something like this

```
const query = this.userRepository.createQueryBuilder('user');

if (option.productId) {
  query
  .leftJoinAndSelect('user.products', 'product')
  .where('product.id = :productId', { productId: option.productId })
}

if (option.organizationId) {
 query
 .leftJoinAndSelect('user.organization', 'organization')
 .where('organization.id = :organizationId', { organizationId: option.organizationId });
}

tempResult = await query.getManyAndCount();
```

Comment: TY  for your help.That's the best way to use it.